# How to use a js function for a particular session in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session-variables

There are two panels. One is for admin and another is for other users. Admin can do anything where other users can do very few things.

There are two tables in a page. One is for Friday and other is for Saturday. I want to set the choice limit of radio button selection from a table. User can not select more than 3 slots out of 4 slots from Friday table. But admin can select all. How can I control this javascript function for admin?

Here is my js function:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //table fri
    $("#fri input[type='radio']").change(function(){
        var count = $("#fri input[type='radio']:checked").length;
        if(count>3){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
          alert("You cannot add more than 3");
        }
    });
    //table sat
    $("#sat input[type='radio']").change(function(){
        var count = $("#sat input[type='radio']:checked").length;
        if(count>3){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
          alert("You cannot add more than 3");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: as long as PHP is running, your JS is nothing but text. text that can be printed. or not be printed. depending on whether or not a PHP-variable is true or false, for example. also: don't forget server side data validation - everybody can outsmart or disable javascript code.

Comment: Any user can do anything in javascript. You need to validate user input in php.

Comment: How can you differentiate between a regular user and an admin?

Comment: admin id is fixed. Here is only one admin. So, it is easy to differentiate between user and admin by checking id.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply put an if else condition in the script.

```
        //table fri
        var admin = <?php echo ($admin) ? 1: 0?>; // $admin holds current user type admin / not
        $("#fri input[type='radio']").change(function(){
            var count = $("#fri input[type='radio']:checked").length;
            if(!admin && count>3){
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
              alert("You cannot add more than 3");
            }
        });
```

Comment: This implies that there's some sort of user management system with flags on whether a user is regular or an admin. The OP made no statement that such a system is in place.

Comment: He does mentioned "But admin can select all". so there must be a backend which differentiate user & Admin

Comment: Either that or the OP wants us to show them how to implement one.

Comment: I presume he has the user management set perfectly, but he has problem working on javascript/jquery. am trying to help him out on that basis.